# Android notification using fire base

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I am developing push notification in webapi. Recently I have upgraded to fire base and using the below code.

```
string deviceId = "dmsGj47_Ulk:APA91bEMkevJzP2_mV2ALCSc_kSTZw57gMBEP2TWtHkrPl1VGTPJYvb0Be_F0zrzsttk78wopecHT_Af3ShAU39sMku0Ht09Pz22YevWkk6hkHjjl87DEvz_7mUJ3vGc05j4n0wjfKR7";
            string message = "Demo Notification";
            string tickerText = "Patient Registration";
            string contentTitle = "Hi";
            string postData =
            "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + deviceId + "\" ], " +
              "\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"" + tickerText + "\", " +
                         "\"contentTitle\":\"" + contentTitle + "\", " +
                         "\"message\": \"" + message + "\"}}";

            string apiKey = "";

            string response = SendGCMNotification(apiKey, postData);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "notification sent");
  private string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string postData, string postDataContentType = "application/json")
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            Request.Method = "POST";
            Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
            Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
            Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            try
            {
                WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
                HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
                if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
                {
                    var text = "Unauthorized - need new token";
                }
                else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
                {
                    var text = "Response from web service isn't OK";
                }
                StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseLine = Reader.ReadToEnd();
                Reader.Close();
                return responseLine;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            return "error";
        }
```

When i run the above piece of code i get error "`{\"multicast_id\":6423299842549772135,\"success\":0,\"failure\":1,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"error\":\"MismatchSenderId\"}]}".` 
In https://console.firebase.google.com/project/androidnotification-17721223233/settings/general/ in setting option there is a General tab. Inside general tab there is Web API Key. Under cloud messaging tab i can see Server key,Legacy server key and sender id. In the above code for api key i used Server key,Legacy server key and webapi key but all fails. May i know which is the correct one to use? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
    Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
    Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={1}", "507022575461"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set sender ID in http-header

Under cloud messaging tab, server key is sender ID.

In http-header :

'Content-type: application/json'

'Authorization: key=AAAA0...' <= your key here.

Send POST request to this address:
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May i know is this is the way to set senderid in header?     Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("SenderID: key={1}", "32323233"));

Comment: key : 'Authorization',    value = 'key=AAAA6pm...'

Comment: Thank you. i updated my code and got error in the senderid header as Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.. May i know what is the correct way to add it?

Comment: Try Request.Headers.Add('Content-Type : application/json') and Request.Headers.Add('Authorization : key=AAAA...')

Comment: 'Authorization : key=[your key]'

Comment: In Firebase console, Under cloud messaging. Do not use Legacy server key and Sender ID. Use Server Key

Comment: Thanks i clicked on overview and clicked on add firebase to your webapp and then i copied apiKey. Now i am getting 401 error.

Comment: This is my php code to send FCM message. $header[] = 'Content-type: application/json'; $header[] = 'Authorization: key=AAAA...';

Comment: Try in http client. before making Java code. If you use mac, Use CocoaRestClient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156450/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-younghwa-park).

Answer (score 0):

The error massage is `MismatchSenderId`. If you run this code on android, you should put `google-services.json` inside the `app` folder of your application and it should be the one that is created for your application in `firebase console`. If you have this file in your android project, open it and check that value of `senderID` is the same as the senderId of this `server key` that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not using any andrioid stuff here. I have written pure .net code. May i know where i have to put google-services.json file in visula studio?